# XERO api remove tenant connections after login

Tags: xero-api

We use XERO to authenticate and sign in to our app on firebase, however, we dont want a user to connect with multiple organisations, we just want a user to sign in and choose a single organisation.

If we remove all tenant connections from our app once a user have finished signing in, this will solve our problem, and we already do this upon logout for the same reason.

I just wanted to find out, is there any implications of doing this ? Will our logged in user still be able to make api calls and get new access tokens ?

I could not find any info of this in the XERO docs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The list of connected tenants represents the orgs the user has authorized your app to interact with their Xero data on their behalf. Deleting the connections by making a DELETE call to the connections endpoint with a specified connection ID will effectively un-authorize your app to interact with that orgs Xero data until the user reauthorizes your app to do so.

So, the shorter answer is - no, you won't be able to make api calls after disconnecting.

Comment: This is interesting, because I was still able to make api calls after making a DELETE call to the connections endpoint. Since I already have the user's tenantid and refresh token saved. Perhaps I wont be able to request a new access token once it has expired. The api is not 100% clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are after is limiting the XeroAPI `access_token` to only be able to write to a single org at a time. This can be achieved through your UX by simply deleting all connections if they try to go through your authorize flow a second time.

That way you are limiting their API connection to a single org, and if they want to change the org they are connecting to they can use your UI to disconnect/reconnect to another one.

### XeroAPI Documentation

> https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/auth-flow

**Removing connections**
If you would like to remove an individual tenant connection from your app (e.g. a user wants to disconnect one of their orgs) you can make a DELETE request on the Connections endpoint:

```
DELETE https://api.xero.com/connections/{connectionId}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is kinda what I am looking to achieve. So XERO users can have multiple organisations connected to a single account. My issue is that when they log in, they might log in and select one organisation. Then they might log out. Then they might log in again authorising with XERO and choosing another organisation. Now, when we go through OAuth, we are no longer dealing with a single organisation, but 2 or 3 etc. We can detect which organisation is the one we are connecting with by by looking at the auth data and the latest updated utc time in the connections list, however,

Comment: the user can no longer choose which one to log in with when signing in, since XERO only says "connected with 2 organisations". And the only way for a user to select a single one is to go to their XERO account and remove the connections and then log in again. We use XERO oath to mint our tokens for Firebase. All I want is for a user to choose a single organisation when logging in (in the case where they have multiple to their name.

Comment: Yeah you can just disconnect all orgs prior to letting them click the authorize url again. Glad you got it sorted.